# AngularJS : tomorrow's date and yesterday's date with some ng component

Tags: angularjs, date

```
$scope.date = new Date();   
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
```

I have written something like this, and I know its not correct. Please correct me to display it in this format `{{date | date:'EEE, dd MMM yyyy'}}`

**Edit 1:** I want the tomorrow's date to be displayed on click of right arrow button and yesterday on left arrow button click at same position where Wed, Sept 3, 2014. Hide/show feature, how to code, I don't understand how to get it using angular. Reference image
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=full+calendar+day+view&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=PIqjVbP4FIijugS3qYOgBg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1360&bih=595#imgrc=2E7vtXzvWMYS0M%3A

Comment: its correct, it gives you tomorrow's date

Comment: what is your question? are you getting a wrong answer or do you want it in tge "dd mmm yyyy" format?

Comment: Please, check Edit 1 in the question to understand my requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you want something like this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/9q8u7fyg/3/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p><a href="" ng-click="showToday = true; showTomorrow = false">Left arrow</a></p>
    <p><a href="" ng-click="showTomorrow = true; showToday = false">Right arrow</a></p>
    <span ng-show="showToday">Today: {{date | date:'EEE, dd MMM yyyy'}}</span>
    <span ng-show="showTomorrow">Tomorrow: {{tomorrow | date:'EEE, dd MMM yyyy'}}</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showToday = false;
    $scope.showTomorrow = false;
    $scope.date = new Date();   
    $scope.tomorrow = new Date();
    $scope.tomorrow.setDate($scope.tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..please can you modify it for the Edit 1 in question.

Comment: Thanks...Actually, if tomorrow is displayed, today should hide at the same time(vice versa) and the display position should be the same. Its like how we do in javascript using a div tag, assigning id to it and calling the function hide/show.

Comment: I did a last edit, but I don't want to do any more, you need to write your own code.

Comment: Does not solve your problem my answer? Can you consider to accept it after all?

Comment: Partially...I guess there is no way in Angular to do two events simultaneously