# How to set date and time 24 hours from current date using Date object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date

I am using angular-bootstrap dateandtimepicker module so in below code when user launch browser i want to set date and time 24 hours earlier from currrent date and time , How can i achieve that task using `Date` object ?

main.html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateRangeStart" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownStart', renderOn: 'end-date-changed' }" data-on-set-time="startDateOnSetTime()" data-before-render="startDateBeforeRender($dates)"></datetimepicker>
</ul>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.dateRangeStart = new Date();
$scope.dateRangeStart.setHours($scope.dateRangeStart.getHours() - 24);
console.log($scope.dateRangeStart);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : tomorrow's date and yesterday's date with some ng component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378925/angularjs-tomorrows-date-and-yesterdays-date-with-some-ng-component)

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What result do you get? What did you expect? Note that not all days are 24 hours long were daylight saving is observed. Possibly a duplicate of [*Add +1 to current date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Js date object is simple and also smart, doesn't just add 24 hours, accounts for daylight savings and new month/year. Just use the following:

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: I was looking for yesterday date i used -1 instead of +1 so that works for me

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []); 
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

    var todaysDate = new Date();    
    var tomorrowsDate = new Date().setDate(todaysDate.getDate()+1);    
    var formattedDate = new Date(tomorrowsDate);

    console.log(formattedDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the millisecond value to roll back a whole day from a certain day:

```
currentDate = new Date();
previousDay = new Date(currentDate - 86400000);
alert(previousDay);
```

Comment: But not all days are 8.64e ms where daylight saving is observed.